# MySQL Find all orders that contain a certain product, and only that product

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
ORDERS
id
customer_name
```

and

```
ORDER_LINE_ITEMS
id
orders_id
product_id
```

How do I find all orders that contain only a single item, specifically where ordered product_id = 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can be extract simply like:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE ID IN
    (SELECT ORDERS_ID FROM ORDER_LINE_ITEMS 
         WHERE PRODUCT_ID = 2
         GROUP BY ORDERS_ID
         HAVING COUNT(ORDERS_ID) = 1
    )
```

if you want as of your comment to have only the orders which has Product_id = 2 and not having any other  product then the sql should be like:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE ID IN
    (SELECT ORDERS_ID FROM ORDER_LINE_ITEMS 
         WHERE PRODUCT_ID = 2
         GROUP BY ORDERS_ID
         HAVING COUNT(ORDERS_ID) = 1
    )
and id not in
    (SELECT ORDERS_ID FROM ORDER_LINE_ITEMS 
         WHERE PRODUCT_ID <> 2
    )
```

Comment: thank you, this however returns orders that contain product_id 2.  it does not single out the orders that ONLY contain product_id 2.  Any ideas for modification?

Comment: Please see the second requested query.